# Can a dielectric have decoupled mechanical and electrical quantities?

Tags: dielectric

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric), they define the dielectric as an electrical insulator that can be polarised by an applied electric field with the relation between electric displacement and electric field as follows:

$$ D = \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r E$$
where $D$ is the electric displacement, $\varepsilon_0$ is the vacuum permittivity, $\varepsilon_r$ is the relative permittivity, and $E$ is the electric field.

They don't write an equation that shows a coupling between the electric field and deformation. However, at the end of the page, examples of dielectrics are given, and one example is piezoelectrics, which do have coupling between mechanical deformations and electric fields

My question is: Is it possible to have a dielectric that can deform but in a way that its deformations are not coupled with the applied electric field? In this way we'll have the two (decoupled) equations:
$$\sigma = \mathbb{A} e(u)$$
and
$$D = \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r E$$
where $\sigma$ is the stress tensor and $e(u)$ is the strain tensor, and $\mathbb{A}$ is the elasticity tensor.

Comment: Does dielectric with intrinsic dipole moment serve as such a candidate? It's unlikely that these two are completely decoupled since there is always induced dipole moment.

Comment: @Bababeluma My professor was asking me to model a material having a dielectric submaterial which has decoupled electric and mechanical properties, so maybe he meant it as an assumption, and I was confused. It might be a special case if the coupling factors are considered negligible, but I'm not sure. For example, a piezoelectric could have decoupled mech. and elec. properties if the ciupling coefficient was taken zero, but I don't know in which cases we can consider that

Comment: There has to be some interaction between crystal deformation and effective polarization, either because the dipoles themselves change or because, and this is more likely, because the separation between the elementary dipoles change and thereby the effective macroscopic average must change manifesting in the permittivity depending on both the strain (stress)  and the  bias field.